# SOAP POST method performs GET?

Tags: java, web-services, post, soap, get

I have a SOAP webservice that is currently POST method, however I saw on my logs that when client is consuming my service there are two calls being made, 1 is to GET the wsdl file then POST to the webservice? Should it be POST call only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think of the WSDL file as a sort of blueprint for a SOAP service.  Given the WSDL, your client application can figure how to use the SOAP service.  So I see nothing wrong with your client app first doing a `GET` to download the WSDL, following by a `POST` to actually consume the SOAP service.

Comment: Does it mean that for all POST method there should be a GET call before the each POST call? Cause this is currently what I am seeing in my logs, is this the standard? I was under the impression, you wsimport the wsdl only once then you can keep calling the method already

Comment: Yes, typically the client will cache the WSDL file locally, but perhaps there is some reason why your app wants a fresh copy each time.

Comment: Understood, i don't see any benefit why they need to keep making more GET calls to the wsdl file for each POST call, I will probably update my webserver to cache the wsdl file. Thanks